# critical section in php between all requests

Tags: php, synchronization

I am making a website in php, in which I want to sell some charge-numbers. For each request, I have to do these operations atomic:

- Asking database for an available charge-number
- marking the charge-number as sold
- increasing a number (in a file or database) which shows the number of clients got a charge-number

I know how to do these operations and if it may help, I am using mysql. But my problem is how to do these operations atomic between all request? I mean how can I force the web-server(apache) and php interpreter to run this part one by one for all request, not in a parallel manner?

P.s: Please make your answers as a solution by php, not a database related solution.

Comment: it's not apache/php related, it's about mysql atomic transactions, watch for mysql innodb engine and transactions [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3382171/Transactions-in-MySQL.htm) or [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)

Comment: and there is no way to make it in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these operations are really database-dependent. So you don't really need to make PHP run code in a critical section; it's enough to serialize these operations at the database.

The simplest way to do that would be to [`LOCK TABLES ... WRITE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html) while you perform these; this guarantees that only one script would be talking to the database at once.

Another approach would be to [`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html) and run all operations in a transaction with autocommit turned off (you should really use a transaction to ensure data integrity even if you decide to go with the table lock though).

**Update:** If you absolutely must do this in PHP, then you can achieve the goal using [`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php):

```
$fp = fopen('sunc_file', 'r+');
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    // Perform database ops here
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // release the lock
}
else {
    die("Couldn't get the lock!");
}
fclose($fp);
```

`flock` in exclusive mode will prevent any other process from locking the guard file and thus let your scripts execute strictly serialized, **but please read the giant red warnings on the man page**!

Comment: your answer is helpful(+1), but do you know any php solution?

Comment: See as well: [mysql table locked after php crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167820/mysql-table-locked-after-php-crashes)

Comment: it's database related (every of your requirements) so why do you want 'php only' way?

Comment: Generally useful for a `one` server environment script.

Comment: Make critical section in php code is not good idea (and will not work) if in future you will run many apache instances (eg. by docker) - in that case two requests from two separate apache instances can go into critical section at the same time - but if you  use LOCKING on common DB table then you will get confidence that only ONE thread write something to DB

Answer (score 7):

Theres a down side to using a php oriented solution, and it's that you can only assure this on a single machine. You can certainly lock it down to a single process in a critical region, but only on a single machine. If you were to have 2 frontend apache/php servers and one backend mysql server, this solution would fail. A MySQL transaction is by far the better solution..

Yet, imagining there is only one machine running this code, it's possible with either the solution Jon posted (using a file as a lock) or if you're on a linux/unix server you can also use IPC methods, and create a system V semaphore with length 1 (a mutex).

```
# in your scripts setup/init phase:
define('MUTEX_KEY', 123456); # the key to access you unique semaphore
sem_get( MUTEX_KEY, 1, 0666, 1 );
# later on, you reach the critical section:
# sem_acquire will block until the mutex has become availible
sem_acquire( ($resource = sem_get( MUTEX_KEY )) );
# queries here ...
sem_release( $resource );
# now that sem_release has been called, the next processes that was blocked
# on the sem_acquire call may enter the critical region
```

Although the file based solution is more portable (works on windows servers) the mutex/sem_* solution is much faster and safer (the auto_release, for example if an application for some reason crashes during the critical region wont block all further requests)

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Here is example code for critical section http://www.bogan.cz/programovani/kriticka-sekce-v-php/. Look for code section.